# Import a Class into all Classes of a Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using C# with Unity, I have a utility Class I'd like to imported into all of the classes of my project automatically.

Is there something like a precompiled header in C# that can do this without explicitly writing "using" statements in each class?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# doesn't have headers. If your class is in the same namespace (which is standard for Unity), you don't have to import it. Otherwise you'll have to import it in any file, as UnityEngine or System.Collections namespace are imported in the template C# script.